# Get indices of all elements that do not include a special character element in R

Tags: r

I want to get the indices of all vector elements that do not include a special character, for example "5".

Example:

```
a<-c("2","2.34","4.5","3","5.1")

with5<-grep("5",a)

[1] 3 5
```

How can I get the "without5" indices?

```
without5<- ...

[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: `grep(5, a, invert = TRUE)` explained in `help(grep)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `invert` argument:

```
a = c("2","2.34","4.5","3","5.1")
grep("5", a, invert = TRUE)
```

However, would advise against dealing with numbers as `character`s unless there is good reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

We can also match the pattern that starts (`^`) with one or more characters that are not 5 (`[^5]+`) until the end the string (`$`).

```
grep('^[^5]+$', a)
#[1] 1 2 4
```